# How to count numbers for every status from history table see output

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

```
lead table

lead_id  |   name    |  mobile
3710        aaa         888888
3713        bbb         777777
3714        ccc         666666
```

```
user table

user_id  |   email    |  pass   |  lead_id
38          ppp         *****       3710
39          qqq         *****       3713
40          rrr         *****       3710
```

```
History table

h_id | lead_id  | status  | user_id

49          3710         not dobale      38
108         3713         doable        38
109         3714         pipeline      38
110         3710         converted      38
111         3715         Login          38
112         3713         converted      38
```

I want to count no of indivisual status for perticuler lead_id.

How to do that ?

But for lead_id 3710 that must be consider h_id 110 not 49 means greater h_id same in case of  lead_id 3713

output should be like this:

```
ouput (for user_id 38)

status            No
converted   -     2   (lead_id is different)
pipeline       -  1
login      -      1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT h.status, COUNT(DISTINCT lead_id)
FROM History h 
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, lead_id, MAX(h_id) h_id 
            FROM History 
            GROUP BY user_id, lead_id
          ) AS a ON h.user_id = a.user_id AND h.lead_id = a.lead_id AND h.h_id = a.h_id 
WHERE h.user_id = 38
GROUP BY h.status
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need to count the most recent status from the history table.  You can get this with a join to an aggregation and then aggregate again.  Or you can use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select last_status, count(*)
from (select h.lead_id, substring_index(group_concat(status order by h_id desc), ',', 1) as last_status
      from history
      group by h.lead_id
     ) h
group by last_status;
```